# Sending message from Facebook app to the user's Facebook friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm making an app that lets people share things with specific friends on Facebook. Example: Alice uses my app, she shares an article with Bob, who is Facebook friends with her. Now my app needs to message Bob in some way and send him the article.

How do I do this? I don't have Bob's email. Can my app send Facebook messages on behalf of the user?

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at Facebook's api "send-dialog":
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

It seems that you could do it pretty easily. The only restriction is that you can't set the message content.

You could fo instance do that:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'send',
  link: 'http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html',
  to:'Bob_FacebookID'
});
```

or using URL redirection:

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?
  app_id=123050457758183
  &link=http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html
  &redirect_uri=https://www.bancsabadell.com/cs/Satellite/SabAtl/
  &to=Bob_FacebookID
```

Would it fit with what you want your app to do?